# morphism between ordered field and integers

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I have recently studied the following paper on the euxodus reals : 
[here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405454.pdf)

I find it quite beautiful that one can construct reals from integers !

However, whilst I could understand most of the article, here is a claim that I need some help proving the following :

Let $(F,+,*,<)$ be an ordered field, and $ \mathbb{Z} $ be the set of integers, then there exists a unique order preserving homomorphism (say $h$) from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $F $ such that

- $h(0)=0_F$
- $\forall p \in \mathbb{Z}, h(p+1)=h(p)+1_F$
- $h(p-1)=h(p)-1_F$

I have successfully proven that this indeed is an order preserving homomorphism however, I can't figure out how to prove the uniqueness of such  homomorphism.

Any help would be greatly apreciated

T.D

Comment: You can use induction to show that $h(n)=n\cdot 1_F$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h(-n)=n\cdot(-1_F)$.

Comment: At first I thought there was some biblical reference. They are talking about  [Eudoxus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudoxus_of_Cnidus), not exodus.

Comment: @conditionalMethod And that's a nice typo therein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ such homomorphism. Then $f(0)=0$, and by induction $f(m)=m\cdot 1_F$ for all $m\geq 0$ using the second condition. Using the third one , we have $f(-1)=-1$, and by induction $f(m)=m\cdot 1_F$ for all $m<0$. Hence such an $f$ , if it exists, is unique and is defined by $f(m)=m\cdot 1_F$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$